# How to find two different elements but with same information using XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find an element that repeats itself in the same page. I tried to use the following XPath's that I was able to find in FirePath, but I didn't have any success running it through my **selenium** automation tests.

This are the two XPath:

```
//div[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input']

(//*[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input)[last()]
```

And this the information on my page:

```
<input class="ui-select-search input-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Selecione" ng-disabled="$select.disabled" ng-hide="$select.disabled" ng-click="$select.activate()" ng-model="$select.search" role="combobox" aria-label="Select box" ondrop="return false;" style="width: 1331px;" type="text"/>
```

[Screenshot with the two fields and part of the HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mVHo.png)

[Another screenshot with the the HTML code of both input text, showed on the first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Qpe.png)

Comment: Please post your complete HTML -  how can we verify the XPath without seeing the whole document? :)

Comment: I'm not able to post the complete HTML, because is part of a internal product of the company that I'm currently working... :(

Comment: I'm not seeing the "two fields" (just one input as already stated) in the screenshot.  I guess I'm not following what exactly you want to do.

Comment: What I want to do is select both of the input text in the screenshot but with different XPath's, because they are selected in different time during my automated test case

Comment: @BrunoPrior Can you update us exact manual steps which you are trying to Automate?

Comment: @DebanjanB Those fields are mandatory parameters to insert a new operation in the system, so what I need is input text on them `browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input']")).SendKeys(text);` and `browser.FindElement(By.XPath("(.//*[@id='selectGenericMult']/child::div/child::input)[last()]")).SendKeys(text);`

Comment: Well looking at the 2nd screenshot which helps a lot more.  It looks like they both have div containers with the same class name (col-md-12), BUT one of them has a "ng-scope" class identifier.  Why not just grab the first one by the "ng-scope" class and the 2nd one by the "col-md-12" with an "[2]"?  Just build out the xpath from there to the element you need.

Comment: Or just use //div[1][@class="col-md-12"] and //div[2][@class="col-md-12"] or something similar.

Comment: @IamBatman I've tried with `//div[@class='col-md-12'][1]` and `//div[@class='col-md-12'][2]` but that only found the label, not the input and I've also tried with `//div[@class='col-md-12']/input[1]` but without success :(

Comment: @BrunoPrior I have answered it below.  Please reply to the answer if it doesn't work for you.  :)

Comment: @IamBatman Thank you very much!

Comment: @IamBatman could you please mark this question as accepted, I'm trying to vote up the answer but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally had some time to look over it (not really, but made time) and this should work for both elements, per your screenshot.  You may need to tweak them a lil', hopefully not though.

First Element:

```
//div[contains(@class,"ng-scope")]//input
```

Second Element:

```
//div[@class="col-md-12"]//input
```

I tested them on my end and they work fine.  Let me know if it's not working for you somehow.

I would suggest looking into how xpath works and study it, it's actually quite fun once you get the hang of it.  You are able to find anything on the screen with just some simple parameters.

Good luck!

Comment: The first element option  It worked fine for me, but the second I've to add a syntax to work, so in the end the second element stayed like this: `//div[@class="col-md-12"]//input[@role]`

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you Bruno and found a way to modify it to your liking.  :)  Have a good rest of your day!

Answer (score 0):

Use below Xpath

```
//input[@class='ui-select-search input-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched' and @role='combobox' and @aria-label='Select box']
```

It will return you all element with same tag

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

To find the element as per the `HTML` you provided you can use the following unique `xpath`:

```
//input[@class='ui-select-search input-xs ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched'][@placeholder='Selecione']
```